# how to use model attribute in views for another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So basically I have a model `Product` which has a price attribute as below.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/products')
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I have this `Main` model which I make for payments, as you can see there is an amount attribute also there:

```py
class Main(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    order_id = models.TextField()
    payment_id = models.TextField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.TextField(default='-')

    card_number = models.TextField(default="****")
    idpay_track_id = models.IntegerField(default=0000)
    bank_track_id = models.TextField(default=0000)

    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Now I want to know how to set amount = price? currently, An user enters the amount manually from a form but I want to pass the price to this function and then set it to the amount and then delete the amount input from the HTML

```py
def payment_start(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order_id = uuid.uuid1()
        amount = request.POST.get('amount')
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('mail')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')

        payer = {
            'name': request.POST.get('name'),
            'phone': request.POST.get('phone'),
            'mail': request.POST.get('mail'),
            'desc': request.POST.get('desc'),
        }

        record = Main(order_id=order_id, amount=int(amount), name=name, email=email, phone=phone, user=request.user)
        record.save()

        idpay_payment = payment_init()
        result = idpay_payment.payment(str(order_id), amount, 'orders/payment/return', payer)

        if 'id' in result:
            record.status = 1
            record.payment_id = result['id']
            record.save()
            return redirect(result['link'])
        else:
            txt = result['message']
    else:
        txt = "Bad Request"
    return render(request, 'error.html', {'txt': txt})
```

This is the HTML

```html
<form action="{%url 'payment_start' %}" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input style="width: 100%;" type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" required>
   <br/> <br/>
   <input style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
   <br/> <br/>
   <input style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
   <br/> <br/>
   <input style="width: 100%;" type="mail" name="mail" placeholder="MAil">
   <br/> <br/>
   <input style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Description">
   <br/> <br/>
   <button style="width: 100%;"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Start Payment</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to copy the price attribute of Product to the amount attribute of Main your form would have to send the id of what product is being purchased with the form data.  Then you could query the model in the payment_start function:

```
product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
record = Main(order_id=order_id, amount=product.price, name=name, email=email, phone=phone, user=request.user)
record.save()
```